# Fix a root problem when trying to go from Home Index page to another area's page

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-7.0

I build an online store as an ASP.NET Core 7 MVC application. I used areas to separate different parts of it.

My home index is outside the `Areas` folders. This home index page displays products. Each product has an `<a/>` tag to redirect to a detail page.

This detail page is put in a subfolder of the `Areas` folder. For some reason I don't understand, I'm correctly redirected to my detail page but it is completely dark. I thought I put all the necessary attributes in the `<a/>` and I don't find a solution for this.

Would you see my code below in order to identify how to fix the problem please?

This is how my folders are organized:

```
wwwroot
Areas
- Admin
- Identity
- ProductDetails
  - Views
    - Product
      - Details.cshtml
  - ProductDetailsController.cs
    Pages
- Index.cshtml
  Program.cs
```

This is the `ProductDetails/ProductDetailsController.cs`:

```
using AutoMapper;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using TheCarHub.Areas.Admin.DTO.Read;
using TheCarHub.Data;

namespace TheCarHub.Areas.ProductDetails
{
    [Area("ProductDetails")]
    public class ProductDetailsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;

        public ProductDetailsController(ApplicationDbContext context, IMapper mapper)
        {
            _context = context;
            _mapper = mapper;
        }

        // GET: ProductDetails/Product/Details/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null || _context.Car == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var car = await _context.Car
                .Where(c => c.Id == id)
                .Include(x => x.CarDetails)
                .Include(x => x.CarDetails.CarMakes)
                .Include(x => x.CarDetails.CarModel)
                .Include(y => y.CarImages)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

            if (car == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var carObject = (car, car.CarImages.First(), car.CarDetails);
            CarDtoRead carDtoRead = _mapper.Map<CarDtoRead>(carObject);

            return View(carDtoRead);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the `Pages/Index.cshtml` page, first attempt:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
    Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div>
    @foreach (var item in Model._carDtoReadList)
    {
        <figure>
            <a asp-controller="ProductDetails" asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">
                <img src="@Url.Content(item.UrlImage.Replace("wwwroot", "~"))" alt="@item.Name" />
                <figcaption>
                    <p>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Year)
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SellingPrice)
                    </p>
                </figcaption>
            </a>
        </figure>
    }
</div>
```

For that first result:

[First result problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McwbH.png)

And my second attempt:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
    Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div>
    @foreach (var item in Model._carDtoReadList)
    {
        <figure>
            <a asp-area="ProductDetails" asp-controller="ProductDetails" asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">
                <img src="@Url.Content(item.UrlImage.Replace("wwwroot", "~"))" alt="@item.Name" />
                <figcaption>
                    <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</p>
                    <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Year)</p>
                    <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)</p>
                    <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SellingPrice)</p>
                </figcaption>
            </a>
        </figure>
    }
</div>
```

And here's the result for the second attempt:

[Second result problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHXh6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how your area routing is configured, but from the structure and url you provided, it looks like your configuration is incorrect.

I made a simple example, you can use it as a reference.

Models:

```
public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public CarDetail CarDetails { get; set; }
}

public class CarDetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CarId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Car Cars { get; set; }
}
```

ApplicationDbContext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Models.Car> Car { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Models.CarDetail> CarDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Index.cshtml.cs:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public IndexModel(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public List<Car> carDtoReadList { get; set; }

    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        carDtoReadList = _context.Car.ToList();
        return Page();
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<div>
    @foreach (var item in Model.carDtoReadList)
    {
        <div>
            <figure>
                <a asp-area="ProductDetails" asp-controller="ProductDetails" asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">
                    <figcaption>
                        <p>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
                        </p>
                    </figcaption>
                </a>
            </figure>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Area structure:

[image]

ProductDetailsController:

```
[Area("ProductDetails")]
public class ProductDetailsController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public ProductDetailsController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
        
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null || _context.Car == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        var car = await _context.Car
            .Where(c => c.Id == id)
            .Include(x => x.CarDetails)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        if (car == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(car);
    }
}
```

Details.cshtml:

```
@model TestApp.Models.Car

<div>
    <h1>Details</h1>
    <div>
        <label>@Html.DisplayNameFor(modelItem => Model.Name) :</label>
        <span>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Name)</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>@Html.DisplayNameFor(modelItem => Model.Description) :</label>
        <span>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Description)</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>@Html.DisplayNameFor(modelItem => Model.CarDetails.Description) :</label>
        <span>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.CarDetails.Description)</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Program.cs:

```
//...
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
//...
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "MyArea",
    pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=ProductDetails}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapRazorPages();
app.Run();
```

Test Result:

Index:

[image]

Details:

[image]

For more details about Areas, you can check this document: [Areas in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

Comment: Hello Chen, thanks a lot!

My controller route was:
app.MapAreaControllerRoute(
    name: "AreaProductDetails",
    areaName: "ProductDetails",
    pattern: "ProductDetails/{controller=ProductDetails}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

And the problem was that a subfolder has a wrong name: ProductDetails/Views/Products instead of ProductDetails/Views/ProductDetails.

Thank you for your time!